# Generating Doxygen documentation in pdf from latex

Tags: doxygen, pdflatex

I am having a problem generating pdf documentation using Doxygen. It generates latex documentation, but when I try to build it using 'make pdf' (or pdflatex directly), I have regular errors. The most common is:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{xtabular*} on input line 5 ended by \end{tabular*}.
...                                              
l.9 \end{TabularNC}
```

The code generated by Doxygen is the following (line 5 to 9):

```
\begin{table}[h]\begin{TabularC}{6}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}{....}\\\cline{1-6}
-\/ &-\/ &-\/ &-\/ &-\/ &-\/ \\\cline{1-6}
\end{TabularNC}
```

If I replace \end{TabularNC} by \end{TabularC}, the error disappears. I do not know Latex and therefore can not know if all this is normal and simply requires a specific configuration, or if Doxygen has a bug. Can someone give me a search track ?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Just the command `make` should be sufficient.

Comment: The version of doxygen is 1.8.8. 'make' or 'make pdf' do the same thing.

Comment: doxygen 1.8.8 is a bit old (August 2014), the current version is 1.8.15 so please upgrade.

Comment: As @albert says, upgrade, and come back if problem still present (by editing your question). To me, you ran into a Doxygen bug.

Comment: As suggested by @albert, I upgraded v.1.8.16 from the sources of the Git repository, following the procedure on http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html, and now everything is working normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the older versions of doxygen there was an inconsistency between the begin and end of the TabularNC and TabularNC environments.

This has been corrected in the newer versions (as far as a quick code check gave in version 1.8.11).